# Powershell: Add Diagnostics/Antimalware to Azure PaaS Cloud Service using ExtensionConfiguration Parameter

Tags: powershell, azure, paas

**I've found the solution after much testing, see updates below**

I've got a bunch (a lot) of PaaS services sitting in Azure, and I need to install Microsoft Antimalware across the board.

"Thats easy!" I hear you say, "Just call *Set-AzureServiceAntimalwareExtension*", and that's what I'm currently doing (after using *Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension* to enable Diagnostics), and it's very tedious as it has to update the whole service (twice if it's running a newer version of the SDK and diagnostics have moved to the service!).

Ideally, I would like to just bundle this into the service deployments, since we do that a lot, and messing about with deploying diagnostics and antimalware is just muddying the waters.  From what I can tell, there is a parameter on the New-AzureDeployment/Set-AzureDeployment CmdLet that allows you to pass in an *ExtensionConfiguration*, in fact it's an array of configurations!

Does this mean I can pass in both the diagnostics and antimalware setup as part of a package deployment? It sounds crazy, and I like it, but can I get it to work? Not currently...

For the moment, this is my method for each service that needs it:

```
Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension –ServiceName $serviceName -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath $diagnosticConfig -StorageContext $storageContext 
Set-AzureServiceAntimalwareExtension -ServiceName $serviceName -AntimalwareConfiguration $malwareConfig -StorageContext $storageContext
```

But it would be a lot easier to simply do this while we're already deploying/upgrading a deployment, something like:

```
$extensionConfiguration = New-AzureServiceExtensionConfig ... ?
Set-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName ... -ExtensionConfiguration $extensionConfiguration
```

Now it looks like we're getting closer, but the New-AzureServiceExtensionConfig needs a bunch of params, *ExtensionName* and *ProviderNamespace* should be ok to work out (simply look at what is there from the current method), but what goes into the *PublicConfiguration* and *PrivateConfiguration*?  I've got a .wadcfgx for the diagnostics, and an XML snippet for the Antimalware configuration, are these the public configs? I can see this is so for existing services, but *PrivateConfiguration* is required.

---

**Update 1:**
I found how to add the Diagnostics as part of the package deploy, we get the keys, create a Storage Context, and pass this in with our .wadcfgx (which has no private config/StorageAccount defined in it):

```
$keys = Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName $storageAccount
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName $storageAccount –StorageAccountKey $keys.Primary
$serviceExtensionDiags = New-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtensionConfig -StorageContext $storageContext -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath "C:\path\to\diagnostics.wadcfgx"
```

Then it's a matter of passing in the $serviceExtensionDiags created above to the package deployment step like this:

```
Set-AzureDeployment -Configuration $configPath -Package $packagePath -Upgrade -Label $label -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot "Production" -ExtensionConfiguration $serviceExtensionDiags
```

---

**Update 2:**
The final piece of the puzzle, getting the Microsoft Antimalware installed as part of the deployment... I used a couple of here-string's but YMMV:

```
$publicConfig = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AntimalwareConfig>
  <AntimalwareEnabled>true</AntimalwareEnabled>
  <RealtimeProtectionEnabled>true</RealtimeProtectionEnabled>
  <ScheduledScanSettings isEnabled="true" day="1" time="60" scanType="Full" />
  <Exclusions>
    <Extensions>
      <Extension></Extension>
    </Extensions>
    <Paths>
      <Path></Path>
    </Paths>
    <Processes>
      <Process></Process>
    </Processes>
  </Exclusions>
</AntimalwareConfig>
"@

$privateConfig = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PrivateConfig>
  <StorageAccountName>xxx</StorageAccountName>
  <StorageKey>yyy</StorageKey>
</PrivateConfig>
"@

$serviceExtensionMalware = New-AzureServiceExtensionConfig -ExtensionName "PaaSAntimalware" -ProviderNamespace "Microsoft.Azure.Security" -PublicConfiguration $publicConfig -PrivateConfiguration $privateConfig -Version 1.0
```

And finally to wrap it all up, we add the Malware config to our update deployment:

```
Set-AzureDeployment -Configuration $configPath -Package $packagePath -Upgrade -Label $label -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot "Production" -ExtensionConfiguration @($serviceExtensionDiags, $serviceExtensionMalware)
```

And we're done!